# Can I call a function within my class constructor that takes the same argument as the constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, oop

There are loads of questions that talk about constructors and functions but none seem to answer this exact question.

I'm aware that there are problems with this "this" keyword in JS but I'm not confident I know how to get around those limitations.

I've defined a class that takes an object as a constructor argument, which then loops over the object and assigns them to the class properties.

I then want to extend those classes and call the same constructor, but altered slightly. My goal is to have a function, `init(obj)` that is called by each constructor.

```
class Thing {
  constructor(obj) {
    init(obj) 
  }
}
```

That's my goal at any rate. I will have a large number of classes that I want to extend. This is my current, redundant setup for the first four classes.

```
class Thing {
    constructor(obj) {
        for(let i in obj) this[i]=obj[i];
        if(!Data[obj.type]) Data[obj.type] = [];
        if(Data[obj.type]) Data[obj.type].push(this);
    }
}
class Role extends Thing {
    constructor(obj) {
        super();
        for(let i in obj) this[i]=obj[i];
        if(!Data[obj.type]) Data[obj.type] = [];
        if(Data[obj.type]) Data[obj.type].push(this);
    }
}
```

So my question: how would I go about making the constructor less repetitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you.

```
var Data = {}
class Thing {
  constructor(obj) {
    this._setFields(obj)
  }
 // you can overwrite this function in child classes
  _setFields(obj) {
    for (let i in obj) this[i] = obj[i]
    this._setType(obj.type)
  }
  // you can overwrite this function in child classes 
  _setType(type) {
    if (!Data[type]) {
      Data[type] = [this]
    } else {
      Data[type].push(this)
    }
  }
}
class Role extends Thing {
  constructor(obj) {
    super(obj)
  }
}

const r1 = new Role({ type: 'role', id: '1' })
const r2 = new Role({ type: 'role', id: '2' })
const t1 = new Thing({ type: 'ting', id: '10' })

console.log(Data)
```